# How do i set a custom output committer in the new Hadoop API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, output-formatting

I have been using the `JobConf.setOutputCommitter()` method to set my own `OutputCommitter` for a map reduce job. With hadoop v 0.20 since this class is deprecated, what will be the alternate to set a custom `OutputCommitter`? I tried setting the property `mapred.output.committer.class` in `Configuration`, but that seems like an invalid property. Have not been able to find an alternate to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by new API - in 1.1.1 at least this is [no longer deprecated](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setOutputCommitter%28java.lang.Class%29) - i think i remember reading that the entire mapred package was prematurely deprecated, and this was un-deprecated in a later release.

If by new API, you mean the mapreduce package over mapred, then the OutputFormats themselves have an associated OutputCommitter, which is acquired via the [`OutputFormat.getOutputCommitter`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/OutputFormat.html#getOutputCommitter%28org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext%29) method

Comment: What would be the java code for this?  I have: Configuration conf = super.getConf(); Job job = Job.getInstance(conf); FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1])); but I couldn't find how do I set the outputCommitter to FileOutputCommitter. It seems that the default in EMR is DirectFileOutputCommitter, but when my output is in s3, then I get file already exists errors